In a light wave what part of the electromagnetic wave is the light?
I assume a high school level physics question is OK to post. I believe it is the electric part. Diagram shows two waves at 90 degrees to each other with no particular orientation. One is the electric and the other the magnetic. Since light can be polarized I assume only one orientation gets through in a polarized filter. I can imagine from the textbook description that the electric field is the "light". On the other hand maybe both waves together are the "light" part of the electromagnetic wave.
I am sorry I cannot find a tag. "Basic Physics" or "High School Level Physics" but I did the best I could.

Light is the combined electromagnetic field. By convention, the electric field orientation is taken as the polarization orientation (electronic interactions are stronger than magnetic interactions).

Excellent question.
Usually electromagnetic waves are absorbed, reflected and diffused through the so-called electric dipole coupling. What we see is proportional to E$^2$. Optical phenomena are usually of this electric dipole type and in this sense light is the electric part.  In other cases the magnetic dipole coupling is the important one, such as in radio transmission and magnetic resonance. Note that in electromagnetic radiation electric and magnetic fields are inseparable.

@mycts Thank you for responding and a well thought out answer that I understand. So there are characteristics of both and highly dependent on the situation we wish to describe.
